# Question related to inclusion-exclusion Principle

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion

So, I just was reading [Hogg and Craig](https://minerva.it.manchester.ac.uk/%7Esaralees/statbook2.pdf)(page 20 *of the book*) and came across the following inequality for arbitrary events $C_1, C_2, \dots , C_k$:

$p1 ≥ p2$.

Where,
$$p1 = P(C1) + P(C2) + P(C3) +P(C4)+\dots +P(C_k)$$ and
$$ p2  =  P(C1 ∩ C2) + P(C1 ∩ C3) + P(C1 ∩ C4)+ P(C2 ∩ C3)+ P(C2 ∩ C4)+ P(C3 ∩ C4)+ \cdots  \cdots  + P(C_i\cap C_j )+ \cdots\cdots$$

But this is obviously false(which can be seen by letting $k=4$ and $C_1 = C_2 = C_3 = C_4$)

There are other results in the book of a similar nature( like $p2\ge p3$ etc..) that can be disproved by a similar argument.

What am i missing?

**(Also, any hints on proving the general result $p1\ge p2\ge p3 \dots\ge p_k$ would be greatly appreciated! )**

the page that i'm talking about is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: I'm afraid this is simply wrong.

Comment: This particular situation may be an exception to the rule that you should not post *images of math*, but should express the Math via [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Please edit your posting to excerpt the author, **word for word**.  If necessary, please screen capture the author's work and post as an image, directly into your posting.

Comment: If all events are equal, i.e. $C_i=C$ for all $i$, then the formula of inclusion exclusion reduces to $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}p(C)=p(C)(-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k1^{n-k}+1)=p(C)$. No confusion there. Furthermore, all statements in the book are correct.

Comment: @user2661923 I have included a link to the book(**not** a link to a webpage where you can buy the book), its page number, and also a screenshot of the page

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle, How is $p_1 \ge p2$ correct? Please provide a proof or an explanation. Furthermore, i agree that the inclusion-exclusion formula is correct. But, i don't see how all the related results hold.

Comment: +1 to your posting, for clarifying what the author is asserting.  It would help if you would review the analysis presented by the author, and find any specific line in any of the analysis that either confuses you, or that you think is invalid.  Then, a MathSE reviewer can explain the validity of the specific line (i.e. intermediate conclusion) in the analysis that you are questioning.

Comment: @user2661923 this just explains why $p(C_1 \cup C_2) \geq p(C_1 \cap C_2)$. It is true that $p_1 \geq p_2$ when you have just two events, because $p_1 = p(C_1 \cup C_2) + p(C_1 \cap C_2) \geq p(C_1 \cap C_2) = p_2$, but, as the original post points out, the inequality fails in general with more than three events. There's no analysis leading up to the author's assertion that $p_1 \geq p_2 \geq \cdots \geq p_k$ in general, so I think the only conclusion to be drawn is that the assertion is false.

Comment: @HaydnGwyn Yes, I realized that after the fact, and so I deleted my corresponding comment.  However, it would help if someone could provide a specific counter example where the conclusion is false.

Comment: The original post mentions the example of $C_1=C_2=C_3=C_4$. Then we have $p_1 = \sum_{i=1}^4 p(C_i) = 4p(C_1)$ and $p_2 = \sum_{i < j} p(C_i \cap C_j) = 6p(C_1)$. If $p(C_1) > 0$, then $p_1 = 4p(C_1) < 6p(C_1) = p_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may take $C_1,\ldots,C_n$, $n\geq 1$ some events. Then the inclusion-exclusion principle states
$$\mathbb P\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^nC_i\Big)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{J\subset\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\\ |J|=k}\mathbb P\Big(\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j\Big).$$

If all $C_i=C$, then the formula reduces (note, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets $J$ of size $k$):
$$\mathbb P(C)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\mathbb P(C)
=\mathbb P(C)\Big(1-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k1^{n-k}\Big)=\mathbb P(C)(1+0^n)=\mathbb P(C).$$

For your specific "counter example", we have 4 singletons, 6 intersections of two sets, 4 of three and 1 of one. That gives as expected $4-6+4-1=1$.

The author then defines $p_i:=\sum_{J\subset\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\\|J|=i}\mathbb P(\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j)$.

But $p_i\geq p_{i+1}$ does not hold in general, as you showed for $n=4$ and $C=C_1=C_2=C_3=C_4$, but rather only for $i\geq n/2$. It has to do with the monotonicity of the binomial coefficients. Only in that case you can use $\mathbb P(\bigcap _{j\in J}C_j)\leq \mathbb P(C_i)$ for any $i\in J$. Then $p_{i+1}$ has fewer summands than $p_i$.

So the author hasn't given the completly correct answer.

Comment: I dont understand the following statement: $\sum_{j=i+1}^n\mathbb P(C_i\cap C_j)\leq \frac{1}{n-i}\,\mathbb P(C_i)\leq \mathbb P(C_i)$ Shouldn't the $n-i$ be in the numerator?

Comment: I'm currently editing it. You are right.

Comment: Also, the result is not as intuitive as it seems. Because, even though each term of $p_1$ is greater than each term of $p_2$, still $p_1$ has $O(n)$ terms while $p_2$ has $O(n^2)$ terms!

Comment: I corrected some of the maths. The number of terms in $p_i$ reduces for increasing $i$ if $i>n/2$.